# Symbol MC32N0 upgrade with VS2008: "InvalidCastException"

Tags: c#, embedded, compact-framework, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I had to upgrade my C# application for a Symbol Mobile Computer (MC32N0) running Windows Embedded Compact 7, that was written for an MC3090 running CE 5.0 and CE 6.0.

Thus, I had to move from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008, because 2008 had the Compact Framework 3.5. (Embedded Compact 7 comes with CF3.5)

So I compiled my application with no errors or warnings, things look great, and I go and install the application to the device, open my app, and get an "InvalidCastException" error.  No idea why.

Why?

Answer (score 3):

I'll tell you why...

For some reason, Visual Studio 2008 decided to cast an ISupportInitialize interface to my numQty object/class.

*(This app is for inventory, so I had to create my own numQty so users could click the "up arrow" to add quantity, or "down" to reduce quantity of any given part.  Maybe because it was "special" that VS2008 decided to mess with me.)*

Here is what Visual Studio did, which I commented out:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
     ...
      //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numQty)).BeginInit();
      //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numQty)).EndInit();
     ...
    }
```

All I had to do was comment out these two lines in the InitializeComponent() method, located in the Form's Designer class (frmMain.Designer.cs).

Hope this helps other Symbol MC32N0 devs upgrading from MC3090.

Comment: You're not alone: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b26f471-54d7-4510-adec-b854d2976de9/isupportinitialize-invalidcastexception-for-derived-controls?forum=netfxcompact and http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/12072/39959.aspx

Comment: Reminder - this comes up any time I upgrade the application for release.  It only shows up if I bring up the UI in Visual Studio. (xxDesign.cs)  If I am only editing code (for the form), then this doesn't happen.